# How do you accept any file that's shared to your Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent

So I have the intent filter setup against one of my activities like so:

```
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.myaapp.sharescreen" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Smokeball">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So in my activities OnCreate I'm check the action

```
            if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
            {
```

Question is I see a lot of areas onliny checking the type against text or image, but if I want to accept any file of any type shared in, what should I accessing on the Intent property?

Thanks

Comment: First: Does your intent filter work? Can the user select your app for any file? Second: What is it that you wanna access? You get an uri i think. Use it. Its unclear what happens and what not happens.

Comment: @blackapps yep the filter works, sharing any file hits my code. But I don't know exactly how to get the Uri, I've tried using (Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); But it returns null.

Comment: Most likely `Uri uri = getIntent().getData();`

Comment: Please check the file you received whether has a matching MIME type. You could check the sample in the link below about how to get the uri. https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#handling-content